# Git Merge multiple branch in a single new branch

Tags: git, github, merge

I have a branch master. It contains a template of a project.

Then in my group, everyone check out into new branch to create their own feature: pin_api, publish_api, home_page, login_page, otp.

Now, I want to merge all of this branch into single new branch(because master is the template, I don't want to mess it even when we can git rebase, this is the request)

I have done these commands (from branch master):

```
git checkout -b new_master
git merge pin_api
git merge publish_api
```

But when I try to `git merge home_page` I get this error message:

```
merge: publish_api - not something we can merge
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Make sure, that you use proper (existing) branch name. You can check it by command `git branch`, which will list you branch names, that you've got in your repository.

Answer (score 0):

The error means `the branch doesn't exist in your local`.

To make sure your local is in sync with remote you can use `git fetch`. This command won't affect your working directory and only fetch the remote branch, tags info into local repo.